# How to improve the prediction of missing data using sklearn regression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, missing-data, non-linear-regression

I need to predict some missing data. I have a dataset of production values over the last 7 year which are supposedly reported hourly. However many datapoints are missing which is why I need to predict them. The data should be yearly periodical with similarity to a sinusoidal curve. Also a correlation to the production values around the same time period should exist. The data set is quite large with over 60'000 however only 52'000 rows has reported values. I currently drop all NA values first to make a prediction model and would then like to predict the missing data with this model.

With my current approach I get however only a value of r^2 of 0.019 and a mean square error of 4031 for the linear regression and for the nonlinear a r^2 of -0.12. With the RandomForestRegressor I got currently a r^2 of only 0.58. How can I approve this?

My current setup is as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(data_dir, file_gen), sep = ',')
df_only_values = df.dropna(subset=plants, how='any')
df_only_values.loc[:,'month']=df_only_values.loc[:,'Datetime'].dt.month
df_only_values.loc[:,'day']=df_only_values.loc[:,'Datetime'].dt.day
df_only_values.loc[:,'hour']=df_only_values.loc[:,'Datetime'].dt.hour
df_only_values.loc[:,'year']=df_only_values.loc[:,'Datetime'].dt.year
Predictors=['month','hour','year']
TargetVariable=['A']
X = df_only_values[Predictors].values
y = df_only_values[TargetVariable].values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=0)
y_train = y_train.ravel()
y_test = y_test.ravel()
#linear
regressor = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
print(regressor.score(X_train, y_train))
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
r2 = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
#non linear
regr = svm.SVR()
regr.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predict_2 = regr.predict(X_test)
r2_2 = r2_score(y_test, y_predict_2)
#RandomForestRegressor
regr = RandomForestRegressor()
regr.fit(X_train, y_train)
random_forest_predicted = regr.predict(X_test)
r2_3 = r2_score(y_test, random_forest_predicted)
print("r2_3 \n", r2_3)
```

Did I do something wrong? Or what other method would you recommend?

Many thanks already in advance for your help.

Best
fidu13

My data looks like:

```
datetime               | A   |
-----------------------|-----|
07/12/2014  01:00:00   | 102 |
07/12/2014  02:00:00   |   0 |
07/12/2014  03:00:00   |  12 |
07/12/2014  04:00:00   |   0 |
07/12/2014  05:00:00   |   0 |
07/12/2014  06:00:00   |  34 |
```

Comment: First of all, I am not sure how you are able to run your algo with your data. Linear Regression for exemple doesn't work with NaN values. You should input with mean (or smth else) or just delete. Second of all, if you really want to use NaN data, Random Forest models are more suited to accept NaN values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and help. I first drop all NaN data at this stage and I am making the regression only with non_Nan values. I want to predict the NaN values then in a second step. The Random Fores approach yielded also only a r2 value of 0.16 sadly.